# Boost example code inheriting from std::exception doesn't link

Tags: c++, linker-errors, custom-exceptions

This article from [boost: Error and Exception Handling](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html) puts forth the following program code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct my_exc1 : std::exception {
  char const* what() const throw();
};
struct my_exc2 : std::exception {
  char const* what() const throw();
};
struct your_exc3 : my_exc1, my_exc2 {};

int main() {
  try {
    throw your_exc3();
  } catch(std::exception const& e) {}
  catch(...) {
    std::cout << "whoops!" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

When compiling with g++ (GCC) 5.2.0, I get the following

```
> g++ -std=c++11 custom_exception.cpp
/tmp/ccmbzPOk.o: In function `my_exc1::my_exc1()':
custom_exception.cpp:(.text._ZN7my_exc1C2Ev[_ZN7my_exc1C5Ev]+0x19): undefined reference to `vtable for my_exc1'
/tmp/ccmbzPOk.o: In function `my_exc1::~my_exc1()':
custom_exception.cpp:(.text._ZN7my_exc1D2Ev[_ZN7my_exc1D5Ev]+0xd): undefined reference to `vtable for my_exc1'
/tmp/ccmbzPOk.o: In function `my_exc2::my_exc2()':
custom_exception.cpp:(.text._ZN7my_exc2C2Ev[_ZN7my_exc2C5Ev]+0x19): undefined reference to `vtable for my_exc2'
/tmp/ccmbzPOk.o: In function `my_exc2::~my_exc2()':
custom_exception.cpp:(.text._ZN7my_exc2D2Ev[_ZN7my_exc2D5Ev]+0xd): undefined reference to `vtable for my_exc2'
/tmp/ccmbzPOk.o:(.rodata._ZTV9your_exc3[_ZTV9your_exc3]+0x20): undefined reference to `my_exc1::what() const'
/tmp/ccmbzPOk.o:(.rodata._ZTV9your_exc3[_ZTV9your_exc3]+0x48): undefined reference to `my_exc2::what() const'
/tmp/ccmbzPOk.o:(.rodata._ZTI9your_exc3[_ZTI9your_exc3]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for my_exc1'
/tmp/ccmbzPOk.o:(.rodata._ZTI9your_exc3[_ZTI9your_exc3]+0x28): undefined reference to `typeinfo for my_exc2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have seen the identical technique used elsewhere, suggesting to me that this should compile (and link) silently. (As an example, I cite Anthony Williams *C++ Concurrency in Action* p. 45 where he inherits from `std::exception` to make `empty_stack` for the thread-safe stack example.)

I have tried to `#include <exception>` and despite the fact that this isn't a C++ library problem, I even tried the `-lstdc++` flag on the advice of people with similar problems---out of desperation.

I understand that in `std::exception`, `what()` is virtual, meaning I should define it---so I'm not sure why it should compile in the first place, but I'm frustrated that it apparently does for other people.

My questions are two: (1) What is the problem, and why does it work for others? (2, conditionally) New to C++, I should also ask what is a good way to implement `what()` (assuming I will have to) in the most minimal way, since I don't actually want to pass a string with my exception. I don't need to inherit from deeper in the hierarchy, such as `std::runtime_error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to C++14 (N3936) [basic.def.odr]/3:

> A virtual member function is odr-used if it is not pure.

So `my_exc1::what()` and `my_exc2::what()` are *odr-used*, even though they are never called. Then we have [basic.def.odr]/4:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic required.

So this whole program has undefined behaviour, but the compiler/linker is not required to diagnose it.

The rationale for this lax requirement is to make a linker's job easier: if the linker happens to be able link without including a call to this function or whatever, then it can do so; the C++ standard does not require the linker to do some sort of whole program analysis to determine whether all *odr-used* functions have bodies.

---

So this code is bugged and it should have bodies for both of those functions. It also should have `#include <exception>`.  For the people who compiled and executed this code; their `iostream` included `exception` (which is permitted but not required), and their linker manifested the undefined behaviour as appearing to link correctly.

---

To provide a body it is as simple as:

```
char const *what() const throw() { return ""; }
```

(assuming you're fine doing it inline). Of course you could return some other fixed string such as `"my_exc1"`. Note that if you only want to return `""` then you do not need to re-declare `what()` at all.

Comment: Re: your "Note that" sentence, I'm just a bit blown away by the idea that code reliant on undefined behaviour made it into these two rather well reputed sources; particularly the Williams book. I'm not saying your wrong! But if you are right there is a lot to be upset about. RE: your proposed `what()`, It does work, but I don't like the idea of constructing a string (or doing anything that may throw and exception) in an exception. Should I worry about that?

Comment: @Timtro `""` is a literal of type `const char[1]`, it has static storage duration and does not require any runtime construction, and cannot throw. This is why (I presume) `what()` returns a pointer, and not a `std::string`.

Comment: I didn't know that virtual functions were automatically *odr-used* until now,  the language is very complicated and experts overlook things regularly!  That's why collaboration is so valuable.

Comment: Also, NB: In ISO/IEC 14882:2011, I found your quote from [basic.def.odr] in [basic.def.odr]/2 and not /3. Perhaps we are each reading from different versions of the standard.

Comment: I just looked in the exception header file, and unless I'm mistaken, isn't what() a pure virtual function? It has no definition, but appears as an abstract specification in the class.

Comment: @Timtro `my_exc1::what()` is not pure because it doesn't have `= 0;` in its declaration. But it is virtual because it overrides a virtual function. I don't think `std::exception::what()` is allowed to be pure anyway (see [exception]/9). Also, I'm using N3936 which is very close to C++14.

Comment: The code you quoted has a copyright 2003 note at the bottom of the page (although I checked old versions of the standard and this same ODR rule has been there since C++98)

Comment: I think I understand now. Being new to C++, I mistakenly thought that simply not including a definition made it pure. Thanks again. P.S. You're quite right that C++ is a complicated language! Though I love it so far, I do miss the comfort I had with C. I couldn't go back though.